# keycloak custom identity provider giving build error .I have implemented a custom AbstractIdentityProvider but getting build error

Tags: authentication, security, keycloak, openid-connect, idp

I have implemented a custom idp class extending AbstractIdentityProviderMapper .
and i am getting below error while building and i am using keycloak 17 :

ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.MainClassBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to record call to method public void org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakRecorder.configSessionFactory(java.util.Map,java.util.Map,java.util.Map,java.lang.Boolean)
at io.quarkus.deployment.recording.BytecodeRecorderImpl.writeBytecode(BytecodeRecorderImpl.java:509)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.MainClassBuildStep.writeRecordedBytecode(MainClassBuildStep.java:444)

**Entire Problem statement is well mentioned** [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-not-using-custom-storage-provider-when-storing-user-retrieved-from-external-idp-like-google/18446/6?u=vijender9423)

I have implemented a abstractIdentityProvider mapper to call logic execution upon authentication from external idp .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Entire problem statement with code is mentioned here : https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-not-using-custom-storage-provider-when-storing-user-retrieved-from-external-idp-like-google/18446/6?u=vijender9423